# Using XmlRootElement in JAXB to avoid root JAXBElement

Tags: jaxb

I am unmarshalling messages conforming to the schema below and would like the returned root element to be of class Bar. Instead, the root element returned is always a JAXBElement containing the name 'foo' with a value equal to the desired Bar element.

I think that XmlRootElement can be used to do this in a bindings file but haven't got this to work yet. Any ideas?

```
<xsd:element name="foo" type="Bar"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Bar">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="goo" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have added, though, that I can't change the schema(s). In fact this is a simplified case and in real life Bar is imported from another schema.

Answer (score 1):

Since there could be many global elements that correspond to a global complex type, a JAXB impl does not generate an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on these classes.  You could declare the element with an anonymous complex type.

```
<xsd:element name="foo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="goo" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

When the `unmarshal` method returns an instance of `JAXBElement` you can obtain the domain object by calling `getValue()`.

Comment: Thanks Blaise, this works, but I'm looking for a solution without changing the schema. Is it possible?

Comment: @EwanB - The following may help:  http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/03/why_does_jaxb_p.html

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your `xsd:element` with `jaxb:class`, this will generate an extra class for your element. This customization can be done via bindings:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xsd:element[@name='foo']">
    <jaxb:class>
</jaxb:bindings>
```